# addchild with multiple movieclip in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

```
var txt_mc:movieClip=new movieClip();
    createTxt(3)
    function createTxt(_no):void
    {
        var _sy = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<_no; i++)
        {
            var txt:TextField = new TextField();
            txt_fmt.size = _size;
            txt.defaultTextFormat = txt_fmt;
            //txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            txt.selectable = false;
            txt.embedFonts = true;
            txt.x = 0;
            txt.y = _sy;
            _sy = _sy + 25;
            //txt.border = true
            txt.text = "Enter your text here";
            txt_mc.addChild(txt);
        }
        mc1.addChild(txt_mc);
            mc2.addChild(txt_mc);
    }
```

How can i addchild with multiple movieclip.
    I was create a movieclip and wants to addchild in two movieclips which are located on stage.
    please help me out.

I want to txt_mc will be add in mc1 and mc2 and from that code txt_mc is add in mc2 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add the same instance of one movie clip in two different containers. But you can create two similar txt_mc instances and add them to mc1 and mc2.

UPDATE: So, you can modify your createTxt function, so it will return new instance of txt_mc each time you call it. And add it to every container you want:

```
function createTxt(_no):MovieClip
{
    var txt_mc:movieClip=new MovieClip();
    var _sy = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<_no; i++)
    {
        var txt:TextField = new TextField();
        txt_fmt.size = _size;
        txt.defaultTextFormat = txt_fmt;
        //txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
        txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        txt.selectable = false;
        txt.embedFonts = true;
        txt.x = 0;
        txt.y = _sy;
        _sy = _sy + 25;
        //txt.border = true
        txt.text = "Enter your text here";
        txt_mc.addChild(txt);
    }
    return txt_mc;
}

mc1.addChild(createTxt(3));
mc2.addChild(createTxt(3));
```

Comment: Thank you Lvan.     may i call  createTxt(3) function for mc1 and then  createTxt(3) for mc2 ?

Comment: sure, I added an example to my answer.